# Model classes in MVP are just POCOs (Anemic Domain Model, DTOs, or VM)? Should they be entity objects which contain business logic?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, mvp

In the following examples, the classes under the model folder are just POCOs. (Are the DTOs or VMs?)

https://github.com/mrts/winforms-mvp

https://markheath.net/post/model-view-presenter-winforms

Should they be entity objects which contain business logic? Should the business/application logic be all in the presenter? Or the entity objects should be in some core modules which MVP code depends on?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's good to keep in mind that DDD is not just a set of tactical patterns for the implementation part but that it rather starts with strategic patterns such as ***Ubiquitous Language*** and ***Bounded Contexts***. See also https://medium.com/@chatuev/ddd-for-microservices-4778a363c071

So DDD is at first about exploring your problem domain and by getting a deep understanding of it you can then better decide what implementation patterns are appropriate for the different parts of the system. This could then be simple ***CRUD like*** implementations or following ***tactical DDD patterns*** using *aggregates, entities, repositories, value objects*, etc.

> Should they be entity objects which contain business logic? Should the business/application logic be all in the presenter? Or the entity objects should be in some core modules which MVP code depends on?

If you follow tactical patterns from Domain-driven Design then the *[Consumer](https://github.com/mrts/winforms-mvp/blob/master/WinFormsMVP/WinFormsMVP/Model/Customer.cs)* model class should contain business logic.

So considering there was business logic in this example project the *Consumer* would be a so called ***[anemic domain model](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)*** as in this version it is simply some data class without logic.

If there is no complex business logic at all but rather lot's of UI logic and CRUD like data manipulation then following tactical DDD principles might be an overkill and the additional efforts would not pay off. So in such a case there can be no *anemic* domain model as there would be *no domain model at all* but rather only DTOs and view model classes which would perfectly fit the demands.